# embed local image into Mac mail signature

Tags: macos, local-storage, signature, macos-mail-app

I am trying to create Mac mail signature from HTML.

I do all parts ok, but if I use local images from file, images show when composing the mail, but the receiver will not get them.

```
Message-Id: <4753944C-A55A-4305-97F1-A6F02620AC8C>
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 13.4 \(3608.80.23.2.2\))
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    type="text/html";
    boundary="Apple-Mail=_B3C48E7A-0D91-4F4C-A1F6-099510D37FA4"


--Apple-Mail=_B3C48E7A-0D91-4F4C-A1F6-099510D37FA4
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset=utf-8

....
<img border=0 width=92
  height=22 src="file:///Users/zadravecm/Library/Mail/V7/MailData/Signatures/image001.png" align=left
  style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:15px'>
```

how to force image to embed into email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The receiver is not seeing the image because the image src references your computer (in this case the file file:///Users/zadravecm/Library/Mail/V7/MailData/Signatures/image001.png"). 
For the image to be available on the receiver, you have a few options

- Upload the image to a online server and use the server url as the img src
- Embed the image as a base64 String
- Attach the image to your email and reference it in your html

Comment: I want to embed as base64, but the syntax for the mail signature is pretty obtuse. It appears that the signature is encoded even after base64 encoding. Any suggestions?